# How might one disable single-line comments in eslint?

Tags: javascript, eslint

Let's say I have this code in part of a JavaScript file:

```js
/* This comment is fine */

//This is a violation of the style guide

/* This comment
is also fine */

//This
// is also
//a style guide violation
```

Is there a way to make eslint mark *all* single line comments (`//`) as a violation/error?

I don't think that [this link on multiline comment endings](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/multiline-comment-style) is *quite* what I'm looking for.

---

Just if anyone is wondering, a reason (in particular *my* reason) that such an odd style rule might be needed is if you are required to be using an HTML compressor that doesn't properly handle javascript, and you'd like to make sure that when it removes newlines from your HTML that it doesn't comment out your javascript. *cough* *cough* some WordPress plugins *cough* *cough*

Comment: `Is this a violation // of the style guide`, with the comment on the line with the code?

Comment: @iPhoenix yes, single-line comments at the end of any line would be a violation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a few years now, but I'll leave the answer here for those who are looking for an answer to the same question.

Maybe you need the ["eslint-plugin-comments"](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@garvae/eslint-plugin-comments) plugin I made.

P.S.
I recommend to read more about ["multiline-comment-style"](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/multiline-comment-style) rule by Teddy Katz. The ["eslint-plugin-comments"](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@garvae/eslint-plugin-comments) by [@garvae](https://github.com/garvae) (me ) and ["multiline-comment-style"](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/multiline-comment-style) by Teddy Katz can complement each other.

Answer (score 0):

With the [line-comment-position](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/line-comment-position) rule, you can force comments to be on the same line as your code, but this is probably not what you want.

If this is not what you are looking for, you might want to look into writing your own rule for this. There is a [guide for writing your rules](https://eslint.org/docs/developer-guide/working-with-rules) included with the eslint docs. The functions in [this list](https://eslint.org/docs/developer-guide/working-with-rules#context-getsourcecode) with the word "comment" in them may be useful to you.

Comment: Although this doesn't directly fix the issue, it sure can get me a lot closer.

Comment: If you figure it out, you should post your code here as an answer and accept it instead

Comment: Yeah. (Granted this style requirement has since changed)

Comment: for the record, I don't think this answer deserved down-votes. It _did_ help with the issue as far as was possible before @Garvae 's npm package was available. Now that package is available, it only makes this answer _outdated_, not _wrong_. If one doesn't want another package dep, it's still useful.